# How do I prevent PowerShell from failing if Karma has failed tests

Tags: powershell, jenkins, karma-runner

### Problem

When I run Karma via PowerShell for the Baseline Branch, PowerShell reacts in a similar manner as though `Environment::Exit(1)` was executed if there are any failed tests in the results. This causes the Jenkins build to fail prematurely without running the remaining components. I want to bypass this so that the Job only fails if a legitimate issue arises, there are failing tests found when running karma against the Target Branch (branch containing code changes), or the code coverage percentage for new lines is lower than the required minimum.

### Background

I am working with Jenkins, PowerShell, and Karma to provide code coverage tests for a web application. In Jenkins, I have a PowerShell task that executes karma as so:

In the Job, I am checking out two branches (one to act as a baseline the other contains the code/test updates). I restore all NuGet packages, then build the solution of the Baseline Branch. Next, I run karma to get the current coverage. I then build the solution for the Target Branch, followed by running Karma to get the code coverage. Using SonarQube, I am comparing the results to provide new line coverage.

Things I have already tried:

- adding in `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`
- looking into the quality gates
- looking up documentation on `karma start`
- adding `| $true` and `|| $true` to the end of the `karma start` command

### Code Example

```
& $nodePath $karmaPath start $karmaTest --log-level debug
```

`$nodePath` is just the file path to node.exe

`$karmaPath` is just the file path to karma

`$karmaTest` is the file path to the karma.conf.ci.js file

Comment: Have the code exit with the desired exit code: `exit 0`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers And how would you suggest to do that? If I alter the environment Exit code to 0, it still ends the job prematurely, which I do not want.

Comment: If your failing tests don't matter, then they're meaningless tests... remove them.

Comment: @Azu I believe I already suggested how to do that. For further help please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Forgive me, but your statement makes it clear you didn't bother to read through the issue above. Yes, the Baseline branch's tests do matter; however, I am comparing the results of 2 branches within the same Jenkins Job to get new line coverage metrics. Because the Baseline has failing tests, it fails the job as a whole and prematurely ends the entire Job, never giving me the metrics I need.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers No, you gave a suggestion, not an answer. One, that I asked you to elaborate on, but you have not done so. I have also added a section on things I have tried, but this suggestion is not there because it is not clear how you expect me to implement this. Therefore, I will continue my research in hopes of finding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it fails is due to the returned exit code.
If you are running your commands in the Jenkins bash script then Jenkins cancel all remaining tasks. You shouldnt really pass a build anyway if there are failing unit tests.
If they are brittle then you are better off refactoring the tests.

To get around this problem pipe a command after the test script is run.
For example

Lets say you have your scripts defined in your package.json roughly defined below

```
scripts:{
ng: ng;
install: npm install;
test-ci: ng test --karma-config karmaconfig --code-coverage
build: npm build
}
```

Now your jenkins bash script could look like below by utilizing the scripts defined in your package.json.

```
npm run install
npm run test-ci || echo "Tests Failed"
npm run build
```

Comment: Thank you Nanotron, this actually helped a great deal